# Difference in the meaning of these two expressions with construct there is/it is?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider these two expressions:

> It has been a dominant election for X political party. For 9 out of every 10 constituency, **it is a X party representative** who won the election.
>
> It has been a dominant election for X political party. For 9 out of every 10 constituency, **there is a X party representative** who won the election.

Do these two expressions with the "it is"/"there is" construct have the same meaning? I feel like of the two, only the first one is correct; the second one feels a bit awkward to me and I don't know what it means.

Comment: I am having some doubts on the previous sentence, "for 9 out of 10 constituency".
I would use "electoral district", but in any case it should be plural. And I would say "in 90% of all constituencies" rather than the somewhat awkward "9 out of every 10".

Comment: Should be "**an** X party representative".

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use existential constructions there. Simplify.

> It has been a dominant election for X political party.

You have a real subject at hand, so why use a dummy subject?

**X political party has dominated the election.**

> For 9 out of every 10 constituency, it is a X party representative who
>   won the election

Again, the same thing: you have a real subject at hand:

**An X party representative has won 9 of every 10 electoral races.**

Answer (score 0):

Both sound pretty awkward, I would write it as:

> It has been a dominant election for political party X. For 9 out of every 10 constituencies, a party X representative won the election.

You wouldn't say

> this is the dog who barked,

or

> this dog barked.

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but the second is less complicated and flows better.